# JQuery validate on html input on asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter bootstrap and asp.net to build a webpage to capture user information.
I'm using this resource as a reference... 
http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/

I have a master page where I have defined a form

```
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" runat="server">
```

and included the references to JQuery...

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On my webpage I have an input control

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">
                    Your Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="txtApplicantName" name="txtApplicantName" placeholder="First Name and Last Name"
                        runat="server">
                </div>
            </div>
```

The resource has some JQuery code to validate the form fields which I can't get to work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#contact-form').validate(
 {
  rules: {
    name: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    subject: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    message: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    }
  },
  highlight: function(label) {
    $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
  },
  success: function(label) {
    label
      .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
      .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
  }
 });
}); // end document.ready
```

I've changed  $('#contact-form').validate to  $('#form1').validate but it doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="txtApplicantName" name="txtApplicantName">
```

Since the name attribute of your input is "txtApplicantName", you should have rules like

```
rules: {
  txtApplicantName: {
    minlength: 2,
    required: true
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Check the form element in your html, I've just done some experiments and it seemed the form need to have an "action" attribute.

Comment: I've just changed the field to txtApplicantName , still not working.

Answer (score 0):

the name of the rules applies to the class of the textbox 
try this first:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate();
        jQuery.validator.messages.required = "*";
        jQuery.validator.messages.email = "Invalid Email"; //set any error message
    });
```

then this in HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge required" id="txtApplicantName" name="txtApplicantName" placeholder="First Name and Last Name"  runat="server">
```

Once you get the validation working you can mess with the rules for each

EDIT:

Now for other inputs on the form such as maybe an input for email address like this , since it has a class of email it will automatically validate an email address.

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge email" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email Address" runat="server">
```

Now if you want a custome rule - which it didn't look like you needed in your example , but here is how you do it anyways

```
$("#myinput").rules("add", {
 required: true,
 minlength: 2,    // chage to any number you want min-length
 messages: {
   required: "Required input",     
   minlength: jQuery.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
 }
});
```

There are a whole lot more options you can add into custom rules if you want to , look into docs for that, but this is how it would look

Answer (score 0):

`$("#form1").validate();` is wrong,
it should be `$("#<%= form1.ClientID %>").validate();`

or if you want you can leave the code the same and just add this attribute to your form tag

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```